# How to import tesseract of opeCV in android studio

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I using openCV 3.2. Now, I want to import module tesseract in android studio. Can you help me!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Correction:

Tesseract is not of OpenCV in the first place. It is an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) library developed by Google.

Installation of Tesseract is completely independent of OpenCV. The following links can help you with it.

[LINK 1](https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/how-to-build-tesseract-ocr-library-for-android-studio/)

[LINK 2](http://imperialsoup.com/2016/04/29/simple-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract-tutorial/)

Upon installation you can go ahead and use Tesseract with OpenCV

Comment: @lucky Glad I could help  :)